# Log reads and writes to console Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

During debug, I would like to have a live output of how many reads and writes I am using, so I can instantly detect problems with my flutter firebase app. How can I get the number of reads or writes a firebase operation is using?

```
void _logOperation(String type, int amount) => print("${amount}x $type");

// e.g. in a stream
return _exampleCollection.snapshots()..getReads((int amount) => _logOperation("read", amount));
```